# Не работают отступы, как исправить?

Tags: css, reactjs, вёрстка

Верстаю компонент и столкнулся с проблемой - не работают паддинги и марджины. Мне необходимо навбару задать падинг 20 пикслелей но увы, не работает, где-то ошибся...
Код:

```js
<div className={styles.navbar}>
      <Link to={"/"}>
        <h1>Filmoteka</h1>
      </Link>
      <div>
        <button>Sign In</button>
        <button className={styles.signup}>Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```css
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  h1 {
    color: #e50914;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffff;
  }
  .signup {
    height: 40px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #e50914;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    color: #ffff;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: styles.signup - Скорее всего такого стиля не находится, т.к. вы его вложили в navbar

Comment: Если вы не используете никаких препроцессоров, то тогда у вас CSS не правильный.

Comment: это scss, с вложенностью нет ошибок